# Sending set of parameters for IN statement to restful service

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex-5

I think it is a very basic question, but Im new working on this. What I need is to build a webservice that receives a set of id's for building an IN statement.

something like that:

[image]

And the url would be something like that:

... service1/semovie/120,121

Is it possible??

Can you tell me how can I create my template/handler?

Many thanks
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! . This is how I configured my service:

[image: Solution]

And this is the output:

[image]